# Как найти файл если знаешь только имя?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Как найти и удалить файл, если знаешь только имя?

В файловой системе сервера есть папка `PersonPhoto`.
A имя файла соответствует *CurrentUserID*, то есть я не знаю только расширение, а имя файла знаю.

Comment: А у Вас есть несколько файлов с именем: CurrentUserID.*?

Comment: каждый user в этой папке имеет только одну фотографию,а имя этой фотографии это его ID,мне неизвестна фотографию с каким расширением он загрузил,может быть ".jpg",может быть".png".но одно известно точно,что имя файла это его ID

Comment: А что мешает хранить эту информацию где-то, а не восстанавливать post factum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если Вы знаете имя файла вы можете его найти без расширения и тогда удалить:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(
    @"C:\Documents and Settings\user1\localaps\temp", // пример
    "CurrentUserID.*",
    SearchOption.AllDirectories);
try
{
    File.Delete(files[0]);
}
catch { };
```

Comment: это то что мне нужно......
только не знал как найти файлы с любым расширением
большое спасибо